# How to achieve Icon animation on home screen android?

Tags: android, animation, icons

In many `application` after installing the app they provide small icon on the home screen. on clicking on that icon some animation is playing functionality executed by that application

For Exaple in the application named `cleanmaster` they provide boost icon on home screen on cllicking by that some `animation` playing and memory clean up is done. screenshot of that is as folow:
[image]

My question is how to achieve this `animation` on home screen?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not icons. Those are widgets.

[image: CleanMaster 1 Tap Boost Widget]

Here are some links on Android site to get you started

[Widgets | Develop](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

[Widgets | Design](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html)

Comment: you cannot place widget on home screen programmatically, user have to choose widget from widget provider to do so. above app installing shortcut. see AnNE DoM.ini answer that is right.

Answer (score 8):

Actually Clean Master use shortcut(installed with `com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT` action)
After user clicks shortcut, it launches transparent activity (activity with theme set to `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`), gets position of click with `Rect clickPosition = getIntent().getSourceBounds()`
and launches animation in this coordinates